# Mongoose create a subobject in a subobject

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a subdocument in a subobject field, not to update.

**My Schema:**

```
var DemandeSchema = new Schema({
    titre: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    answer: {}
});
```

**My code:**

```
demande.update(
    { name: 'answer' },
    { $push: req.body.answer },
    { upsert: true }, 
    function(error, user) {
        if (error) return next(error);
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
)

req.body.answer = {
  "id": "57f512f4360d8818a4e5ea3d",
  "answer": {
     "122547eee99" : {
        "review" : "1.3",
        "login" : "new"
    }
  }
}
```

But this code doesn't create a new field in my DB, it just updates the field `answer` when I just want to create a new object field in the answer field.

**Actual Result**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f512f4360d8818a4e5ea3d"),
    "titre" : "TEST",
    "description" : "ee",
    "type" : "ee",
    "__v" : 0,
    "answer" : {
        "122547eee98" : {
            "review" : "8.8",
            "login" : "x"
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Result**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f512f4360d8818a4e5ea3d"),
    "titre" : "TEST",
    "description" : "ee",
    "type" : "ee",
    "__v" : 0,
    "answer" : {
        "122547eee98" : {
            "review" : "8.8",
            "login" : "x"
        },
        "122547eee99" : {
            "review" : "1.3",
            "login" : "new"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: answer field should be array, so it can be pushed to array and add new record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var DemandeSchema = new Schema({
titre: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
type: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
answer: []
});
```

Answer field curly braces would convert to square brackets for pushing all new answers.
Conclusion: It creates an array.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push)** operator which works on arrays, use the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set)** operator together with the dot notation to [set the subdocument in the embedded answer document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents).

You would need to preprocess the document to use in your update so that it will have the **[dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)**. The following mongo shell example demonstrates this:

```
var obj = {
        "id": "57f512f4360d8818a4e5ea3d",
        "answer": {
            "122547eee99" : {
                "review" : "1.3",
                "login" : "new"
            }
        }
    },
    update = {};
var key = Object.keys(obj.answer)[0]; // get the dynamic key "122547eee99"
update["answer."+key] = obj.answer[key]; // create the update object with dot notation

/*
    update = {
        "answer.122547eee99": {
            "review" : "1.3",
            "login" : "new"
        }
    }
*/

db.demandes.update(
    { "_id" : ObjectId(obj.id)},
    { "$set": update },
    { "upsert": true }
)
```

---

Using the same concept as above, you can create the documents to use in your update as follows:

```
var update = {},
    key = Object.keys(req.body.answer.answer)[0]; // get the dynamic key "122547eee99"

// create the update object with dot notation
update["answer."+key] = req.body.answer.answer[key]; 

demande.update(
    { "_id": req.body.answer.id },
    { $set: update },
    { upsert: true }, 
    function(error, user) {
        if (error) return next(error);
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and in schema answer: [],

```
 demande.findOne( { name: 'answer' }, function(err, result){
 result.answer.push({ans:req.body.answer})
 var dem = new Demande(result); // Demande is ur mongoose schema model, 
 dem.save(function(err, result){

 console.log(result);
});
})
```